# Reinitialize bootstrap modals after loading ajax content

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap Modals, with normal usage cases it works well, but when adding new content via AJAX I need to make it remap the newly added elements.

I need that function like bootstrap_modal() or bootstrap_modal.init() to be fired after the new content was added.

**I have a table of elements, each element has a modal that contains more information about it, these elements are added using AJAX (with a click of a button) so I want that when I click on that button, the new content loads and the the modal remapping is triggered to take into account the new elements.**

Comment: Are you trying to bind to button clicks or stuff like that once the modal content is updated?

Comment: @RatHat look at the new edit.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, there is a button "add element" that adds a new row or entry into this table but that element itself has another button "show details" or something similar. Does this resemble what you have? Also do you have a bunch of modals or just a single modal that you swap the content on demand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep. to leave a comment on your question, but can you paste some code and let me know what programming language you're using?  I have examples in both c#/ASP.NET and php.